# Powershell JSON data group by

Tags: powershell

I'm working on automation to trigger emails wherin I need to send an email to each email ID(TestValue3) which is read from the JSON file and body of the email should be containing the values of TestValue1, TestValue2 & TestValue4 respective to email ID.

Here same email IDs are appearing more than once so instead of sending multiple emails, I need to group all the information of respective email ID(which are repeating) and send it as one email.

```
{
"Data":  [
             {
                 "TestValue1":  "MyCode35",
                 "TestValue2":  "Some Test Value1",
                 "TestValue3":  "user122@gmail.com",
                 "TestValue4":  "Account1"
             },
             {
                 "TestValue1":  "MyCode38",
                 "TestValue2":  "Some Test Value2",
                 "TestValue3":  "user121@gmail.com",
                 "TestValue4":  "Account2"
             },
             {
                 "TestValue1":  "MyCode56",
                 "TestValue2":  "Some Test Value2",
                 "TestValue3":  "user121@gmail.com",
                 "TestValue4":  "Account3"
             },
             {
                 "TestValue1":  "MyCode35",
                 "TestValue2":  "Some Test Value1",
                 "TestValue3":  "user1234@gmail.com",
                 "TestValue4":  "Account8"
             },
             {
                 "TestValue1":  "MyCode35",
                 "TestValue2":  "Some Test Value1",
                 "TestValue3":  "abc.user1234@gmail.com",
                 "TestValue4":  "Account11"
             },
             {
                 "TestValue1":  "MyCode88",
                 "TestValue2":  "Some Test Value1",
                 "TestValue3":  "user1234@gmail.com",
                 "TestValue4":  "Account32"
             },
             {
                 "TestValue1":  "MyCode45",
                 "TestValue2":  "Some Test Value1",
                 "TestValue3":  "user122@gmail.com",
                 "TestValue4":  "Account18"
             }
        ]
}
```

After updating the code, it returned grouped data.

```
$json = Get-Content -Raw -Path .\filename.json | ConvertFrom-Json
$json | ForEach-Object Data | Group-Object -Property TestValue3
```

Sample email body wherein I will be using these TestValue1, TestValue2 & TestValue4

### User Details

Codes Are: $TestValue1
Test Value Are: $TestValue2
Accounts Are: $TestValue4

Any idea or suggestions?

Comment: The document root object only has one property `"Data"`. You'll want to do `Get-Content -Raw -Path \filename.json | ConvertFrom-Json | ForEach-Object Data | Group-Object -Property TestValue3`

Comment: Why would any of the grouped elements have a `Type` property? The only property names in the JSON are `TestValue1`, `TestValue2`, `TestValue3` and `TestValue4` :)

Comment: Yes I missed that "Data" property. Now I get it but when I try to group the data underlying other property values are getting null. Below is the code ``$json | ForEach-Object Data | Group-Object -Property TestValue3 | ForEach{@{$_.Name = $_.Group.TestValue2}} | ConvertTo-Json``  $json has the json content `` $json = Get-Content -Raw -Path .\filename.json | ConvertFrom-Json ``.  Updated my comment. This is getting only TestValue2 so need to get all the values for that useremail ID

Comment: Please [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74275868/edit) with the code you're having trouble with, comments aren't well-suited :)

Comment: Updated my original post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed the data to better illustrate the usage...

```
$json = @'
{
    "Data": [
                {
                    "Codes":      "MyCode35",
                    "TestValue":  "Some Test Value1",
                    "Recipient":  "user122@gmail.com",
                    "Account":    "Account1"
                },
                {
                    "Codes":      "MyCode38",
                    "TestValue":  "Some Test Value2",
                    "Recipient":  "user121@gmail.com",
                    "Account":    "Account2"
                },
                {
                    "Codes":      "MyCode56",
                    "TestValue":  "Some Test Value2",
                    "Recipient":  "user121@gmail.com",
                    "Account":    "Account3"
                },
                {
                    "Codes":      "MyCode35",
                    "TestValue":  "Some Test Value1",
                    "Recipient":  "user1234@gmail.com",
                    "Account":    "Account8"
                },
                {
                    "Codes":      "MyCode35",
                    "TestValue":  "Some Test Value1",
                    "Recipient":  "abc.user1234@gmail.com",
                    "Account":    "Account11"
                },
                {
                    "Codes":      "MyCode88",
                    "TestValue":  "Some Test Value1",
                    "Recipient":  "user1234@gmail.com",
                    "Account":    "Account32"
                },
                {
                    "Codes":      "MyCode45",
                    "TestValue":  "Some Test Value1",
                    "Recipient":  "user122@gmail.com",
                    "Account":    "Account18"
                }
            ]
}
'@
```

Group and traverse...

```
$SmtpGateway = '127.0.0.1'

$GroupedRecipents = $json | ConvertFrom-Json | select -ExpandProperty Data | group Recipient

foreach ($GroupItem in $GroupedRecipents){
    $body = $GroupItem.Group | Select * -ExcludeProperty Recipient | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
    Send-MailMessage `
        -From 'sender@nowhere.out' `
        -SmtpServer $SmtpGateway `
        -To $GroupItem.Name `
        -Subject 'Here is the mail' `
        -BodyAsHtml "$body"
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Dennis. It gives me the mapped values with your code. In my script I need to use grouped values as a value to variable. So how do I get the values from the group now. I tried ``$json | select -ExpandProperty Data | group TestValue3 | ForEach{@{$_.Name = $_.Group.TestValue1}}`` and it gives Name Value pairs.

Comment: Can you update your original question about what data you need to forward and what the desired format should be? Grouping is mostly used for pretty output or perhaps pivoting.

Comment: Updated the original post